# Unity 5.3.5f1 Crashes in play mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash

I am facing a big problem here. I have a code where i use the InvokeRepeating() method on the start() method to keep track of my "in game time". Every time I click on the play button, Unity just crashes and i have to finish the applicatin via task manager! I really don´t know what to do as I receive no message from the console or any other bug report. Can enyone help me? What can I do to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried checking the Windows Application Log?

Comment: This will be hard to fix without seeing your code. Really hard. My suggestion to you is to start commenting some code from below up and see when it stops crashing.

Comment: I have checked my code and as I said, the problem is the InvokeRepeating() function. Whenever I comment it out or remove it, the problem is gone. But this is not rigth. As its a standart unity code, it makes no sense it crashes. It is an inherently loop like function. I know I can do this by using coroutines but it seems senseless as C# has a dedicated function to do this. Very weird.

Answer (score 1):

Unity will do this if you hit an infinite loop.

Comment: add `breakpoint` in monodevelop, and debug to check whether it is an infinite loop.

Comment: I have checked my code and as I said, the problem is the InvokeRepeating() function. Whenever I comment it out or remove it, the problem is gone. But this is not rigth. As its a standart unity code, it makes no sense it crashes. It is an inherently loop like function. I know I can do this by using coroutines but it seems senseless as C# has a dedicated function to do this. Very weird.

Comment: To be honest and with my experience, most of the looping controls unity has is moved to a custom coroutine. Personally, I like having control over what is looping, when that loop stops, etc. But, if you read what you said. You remove the InvokeRepeating() and the infinite loop crash goes away. After all, the problem is staring you right in the face. xP If you think this is really a Unity bug and not your error, report it to Unity. Youd be better off moving the function that "repeats" to a IEnumerator.

Comment: "I know I can do this by using coroutines but it seems senseless as C# has a dedicated function to do this. " Really? Move it to a coroutine......